# Upload file using arrow mark in webdriver

Tags: file, selenium-webdriver, upload

I have to upload an excel file in the application.For that, I need to click on one arrow mark (i.e;browse button)which will open up the popup for the user to choose the file from local drives.Below is the code displayed when I did inspect element on the arrow mark.
 "  ".

Also, the path which will display after choosing the file will be greyed out before user selects the file. This will be enabled only when the user chooses some file from the  local.

I was trying below code but it did not work. I think send keys is wrong option as the text path is greyed out.

Help me on this.

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'uploadInp'"));
    driver.findElement(By.id("uploadInp")).click();
    El.sendKeys("D:\\NTN 4\\Demo\\BulkCart_Template.xlsx");
```

Arrow HTML code:-

```
<input id="file1" type="file" value="" style="background-color: red;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);cursor: pointer; padding-top:3px;width:25px;" name="file">
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to click on browser button or open any pop-up. `sendkeys` will going to dump your path in HTML DOM for you

So don't click on browser button while use the same button element to perform `sendkeys` like below:-

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'uploadInp'"));
El.sendKeys("D:\\NTN 4\\Demo\\BulkCart_Template.xlsx");
```

Now you need to click on element which is going to start your upload. As you didn't mention and it's unclear according to your question that which element going to upload your file. Just find that element and click on it normally.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought I copy pasted the below in original question..anyways below is the code which I got when I did inspect element on the arrow mark.                                                                "<input id="file1" type="file" value="" style="background-color: red;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);cursor: pointer; padding-top:3px;width:25px;" name="file">   ". but I am getting error as 'unable to locate element'

Comment: what code you are using to find that element? ... is there any frame present on your HTML dom in between this element

Comment: I am trying to use the element by ID.. There is no frame involved.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("file1")).click();

Comment: do you have more element in HTML DOM with same id?

Comment: Tried that code before asked the question , it did not work.

Comment: WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.name("file"));
        El.sendKeys("D:\\NTN 4\\Demo\\BulkCart_Template.csv");  when I execute the above code, it works successfully and I could able to upload the file. when I try the same code again, it throws error saying Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"file"}... it looks strange for me the same code is working sometimes and not sometimes.. Please advise what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you using any wait like implicit wait  ->  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: No, haven't use any implicit wait.